# How can I map a single Property as part of multiple compound Foreign Keys using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-6

I'm setting up an EF Code First mapping to a legacy database.  The object model is a 1-to-1 of the database schema (no trying to pretty-up the schema).

The database has a table with two compound Foreign Keys, and one column is used in both Foreign Keys.  Here's a pseudo-sample:

```
CREATE TABLE This_One
(
  CommonColumn INT NOT NULL, -- NOTE: This column is part of both Compound FK's
  ColumnOne INT NOT NULL,
  ColumnTwo INT NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT FK_ONE FOREIGN KEY (CommonColumn, ColumnOne)
    REFERENCES Other_One (CommonColumn, ColumnOne),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Two FOREIGN KEY (CommonColumn, ColumnTwo)
    REFERENCES Other_Two (CommonColumn, ColumnTwo)
);
```

For my class-mappings I've been using Data Annotations.  The `ForeignKeyAttribute` that doesn't `AllowMultiple` on it's `AttributeUsage`, so a property can only have a single `[ForeignKey]` applied to it, and the attribute only accepts a single name.

```
// Can't apply the compound keys this way
[Table("This_One")]
public class FKOnProperty
{
  public int Common {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey(nameof(OtherOne))] // [ForeignKey(nameof(OtherTwo))]
  public int One {get;set;}

  ...

  public OtherOne OtherOne {get;set;}

  public OtherTwo OtherTwo {get;set;}
}

// Or this way
[Table("This_One")]
public class FKOnNavigation
{
  public int Common {get;set;}

  public int One {get;set;}

  public int Two {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey(nameof(One))] // [ForeignKey(nameof(Two))]
  public OtherOne OtherOne {get;set;}

  ...
}
```

In a nutshell, I can't use the attribute to specify that the `CommonColumn` is part of two keys, and since both keys are compound I can't apply it on the navigation property.

How can I map two compound foreign keys that have a common property?  Or is it not possible with Data Annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `ForeignKey` attribute on the navigation properties using comma separated string with the property names:

```
public class This_One
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CommonColumn { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ColumnOne { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int ColumnTwo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CommonColumn,ColumnOne")]
    public Other_One Other_One { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CommonColumn,ColumnTwo")]
    public Other_Two Other_Two { get; set; }
}
```

Excerpt from the `ForeignKey` constructor [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKeyAttribute.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

> If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a foreign key property, you should specify the name of the associated navigation property. If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a navigation property, you should specify the name of the associated foreign key(s). **If a navigation property has multiple foreign keys, use comma to separate the list of foreign key names.**